# TFS+Git Require Linked Work Item Branch Policy Options

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

In setting up our branch policies, there are 2 checkboxes related to forcing linked work items:

- Check all pull requests for linked work items

  - Block the merge if there are no linked work items

The first is pretty self-evident, but we're trying to understand the ramifications of checking/unchecking the second item.  We've had no luck trying to find documentation on these options so we're wondering if someone can describe what they do.  Thanks!

Comment: Any reason the second policy is indented here? Is it presented that way in TFS?

Comment: Yes, the second checkbox is not active unless the first is checked.

Comment: Which edition of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you haven't upgraded your TFS to the latest edition TFS2015.3. Just checked my TFS2015.3, the 2 checkboxes are as below, there is no `Block the merge if there are no linked work items`:

[image]

Comment: Correct, we are not seeing that verbiage, but that is a vast improvement!  Much clearer with that terminology, thanks!